# Increasing clicking speed through WebDriverwait using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Is it possible to decrease timeperiod between each click in Selenium? As far as I know, by default webdriver tries to click every half second.

Comment: The default element *lookup* (assuming you defined wait) is half a second. The driver tries to click only when you use `click()` method, and only once.

Answer (score -1):

### click()

[`click()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) method clicks the element which is defined as:

```
def click(self):
    """Clicks the element."""
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
```

`Command.CLICK_ELEMENT` is executed only when call to the `click()` is invoked.

---

Presumably you are referring to invoking the `click()` method once the element is returned through [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.button#btn"))).click()
```

The constructor of [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) is:

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, poll_frequency=0.5, ignored_exceptions=None)

where:
    driver - Instance of WebDriver (Ie, Firefox, Chrome or Remote)
    timeout - Number of seconds before timing out
    poll_frequency - sleep interval between calls By default, it is 0.5 second.
    ignored_exceptions - iterable structure of exception classes ignored during calls. By default, it contains NoSuchElementException only
```

So the *timeperiod* you are referring is the possibly the **`poll_frequency`** which is by default set to **0.5 second** i.e. **500 miliseconds** and this is the time interval between two back to back `find_element_by_*` calls.

If your usecase is to tweak/increase/decrease the **poll_frequency** you can change the [constructor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.html#WebDriverWait) which is as:

```
class WebDriverWait(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, timeout, poll_frequency=POLL_FREQUENCY, ignored_exceptions=None):

    self._driver = driver
    self._timeout = timeout
    self._poll = poll_frequency
    # avoid the divide by zero
    if self._poll == 0:
        self._poll = POLL_FREQUENCY
    exceptions = list(IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS)
    if ignored_exceptions is not None:
        try:
        exceptions.extend(iter(ignored_exceptions))
        except TypeError:  # ignored_exceptions is not iterable
        exceptions.append(ignored_exceptions)
    self._ignored_exceptions = tuple(exceptions)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this using JS function

```
num = 0; //to count clicks
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('yourEl');
function clicker () {element.click(); num+=1;}
setInterval(clicker,0.2);
```